# Keyboard configuration resets on unexpected crash

Tags: keyboard, tower-of-fantasy

I live in a country where power cuts are a thing of everyday life, and where the internet connection is also unstable

I remapped my hotkeys on PC, and everytime I have a sudden power cut or an unexpected logout due to internet issues, my hotkeys are reset to the default mapping

Is there currently a way to save my current mappings and load them if they reset again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround I have found out is to make your configuration file read only, so it can't be reset by the game

It is located at `C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Hotta\Saved\Config\WindowsNoEditor\input.ini`

Since I did that, it does not reset whenever I get a random crash anymore